# How to store XML into Java array

Tags: java, arrays, jsoup

```
I have an XML with a list of beaches.
```

Each entry looks like:

```
<beach> 
    <name>Dor</name>
    <longitude>32.1867</longitude>
    <latitude>34.6077</latitude>
</beach>
```

I am using Jsoup to read this XML into a Document doc.

Is there an easy way to handle this data?
I like to be able to do something like this:

```
x = my_beach_list["Dor"].longitude;
```

Currently I left it in Jsoup Doc and I am using:

```
x = get_XML_val(doc, "Dor", "longitude");
```

With get_XML_val defined as:

```
private String get_XML_val(Document doc, String element_name, String element_attr) {
    Elements beaches = doc.select("beach");
    Elements one_node = beaches.select("beach:matches(" + element_name + ")");
    Element node_attr = one_node.select(element_attr).first();
    String t = node_attr.text();
    return t;
}
```

Thanks
Ori

Comment: Use an actual XML object-binding library (like JAXB), parse the XML to Java objects, and store those Java objects in your list (or in a Map<String, Beach>, where the key is the name of the beach, since that's what you seem to desire)

Comment: Hi,  I did not know Map. Exactly what I need. Thanks and sorry for the delay :-)

Answer (score 0):

Java is an object oriented language, and you would benefit a lot by using that fact, for instance, you can parse your XML into a java data structure once, and use that as a lookup, ex:

```
class Beach {

    private String name;
    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;

    // constructor;

    // getters and setters;
}
```

now when you have your class set up, you can start to parse your xml into a list of beach objects:

```
List<Beach> beaches = new ArrayList<>(); 
// for every beach object in the xml
beaches.add(new Beach(val_from_xml, ..., ...);
```

now when you want to find a specific object, you can query your collection.

```
beaches.stream().filter(beach -> "Dor".equals(beach.getName()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XPath` evaluator to execute queries on the xml directly and can get the results. For Example : the `xpath` expression to get **longitude** value for a **beach** with name **Dor** is : `/beach[name="Dor"]/longitude`

The corresponding java code to evaluate xpath expressions can be written as :

```
private static void getValue(String xml) {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new StringBufferInputStream(xml));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile("/beach[name=\"Dor\"]/longitude").evaluate(doc,
                XPathConstants.NODESET);

        System.out.println(nodeList.item(0).getTextContent());
    } catch (IOException | ParserConfigurationException | XPathExpressionException | SAXException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The above method prints the longitude value as : 32.1867

More on Xpaths [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp).